# Ignore <base> tag in a v-html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use v-html directive to safely render some html coming from my DB: `<div v-html="htmlContent">`.
Some of the html contents include `<base target="_self" href="http://some.other.website">` tags. The moment this html is rendered, "http://some.other.website" becomes the base of any request in the page, and it ends with tones of errors of course.

Is there a best practice how to remove or ignore such tags? (I guess `<script>` could also cause some unwanted behaviors).

The only "pure" solution I have in mind is to use `String.replace` with some regex to detect potentially problematic tags.

Comment: It the html altered before it is injected into the template?  So if you console.log it, does it still have the changed URL?